# Arrange brightness sliders in command strip for multiple monitors

Tags: display, settings, touch-bar, macos

I have a multi-monitor setup with two external monitors (whose brightness is controlled by OS X, not physical controls) and the built-in laptop display. I have my displays arranged with the two external monitors flanking either side of the laptop. When I go to adjust the brightness of the displays using the command strip the brightness indicators place both external displays to the left of the built-in display, and additionally reverse the order of the controls (the right monitor is controlled by the left-most brightness slider). I am looking for a way to re-arrange the brightness sliders in the command strip to reflect the real-world arrangement of my displays.

How I actually have my displays arranged:
[image: real world]

How the command strip has its controls arranged:
[image: command strip]